# MQTT Broker - Excessive CPU and Memory Usage

Tags: memory-management, mqtt, cpu-usage, mosquitto

I have an MQTT(Mosquitto) service running in a docker container for a production site(hosted on AWS EC2). The reason for running it within a container is to ensure portability since we use this service in multiple places.

Recently, we have been observing that MQTT over time, starts eating up a lot of resources(CPU and Memory), due to which it turns out that we start losing information that has been transmitted over MQTT via QoS 1. To resolve this issue, the following approaches have been tried out:

- Delete the persistence file that the MQTT broker uses
- Delete the complete MQTT volume
- Restart the container

The above steps seem to work for the time being, but do not completely address the issue. We also went a step further to increase the number of resources available to MQTT(EC2 CPU and Memory), but similar to the above steps, it seems to just push back the problem and not address it.

Could you suggest ways in which we can address this issue? Furthermore, it would be helpful, if anyone can suggest how to profile the MQTT Broker as well, for heap usage, topics, clients, disconnects/connects, etc.

Currently, we use the following MQTT configuration file:

```
# mount to /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf

# sys_interval 60

persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/

# This causes every change to trigger retained data save
autosave_interval 60
queue_qos0_messages true
store_clean_interval 20
max_queued_messages 100000
max_inflight_messages 10000
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/passwd
acl_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/acl

connection_messages true
log_dest stdout

persistent_client_expiration 1h
```

Note: The clients that we use to connect to the MQTT Broker, are written in NodeJS and Python. And with all the clients we pass the clean-session option as `true`.

Running the following command on the Mosquitto server:
`mosquitto --help`

The response received is:

```
mosquitto version 1.4.12 (build date 2017-06-01 13:03:46+0000)

mosquitto is an MQTT v3.1.1/v3.1 broker.
```

Comment: We need to know more about your client profile, do they all have static client ids or are you randomly generating them? It would also probably be useful to know what version of mosquitto you are running

Comment: None of the clients have static client ids, All of them are dynamic, but with the clean session option enabled

Comment: We still need to know what version of Mosquitto you are running.

Comment: The root cause could be anywhere - docker, mosquitto bugs or config, OS config. We have been testing for 25 years, and have seen it all. There is no easy solution but to do long-term testing, eg. https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2017/11/long-term-testing-with-mimic-simulator.html . One alternative is to run 10 times the number of clients at 10 times the rate, eg. with a simulator, to cut down your testing time by 100.